# CORS errors with Chrome/Tomcat8

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I'm integrating a third party library into an Ember.JS application. The library dynamically creates an `<iFrame/>` window which makes some API calls back to its server component. The server side is hosted on a machine different from where the main app is being hosted (localhost). I think that I've enabled CORS support for the Tomcat8 server that's hosting the library's API, but it keeps giving me errors.

Below is the Tomcat config for the library's server portion
/home/ec2-user/path/to/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>accept,access-control-allow-origin,user_name,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method,Cache-Control,Connection
,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I specifically left out `cors.allowed.origins` as the docs say that if you don't specify it, the default is `*` (all origins).

When I bring up the web page that has the `<iFrame>` in it, I get the following error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://dev.company.com:9090". Protocols, domains, and ports must
>   match.

The library's code that is actually causing the error is this:

```
var that = this;
var frame = this.frame = $('<iframe class="' + this.options.iframeClass + '"/>').attr('src', this.options.urlPath + '?template=' + encodeURIComponent(this.options.templateName) + '&paramCount=1&param1=input=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&layout=FIT');
frame.load(function () {
    frame[0].contentWindow.Plugin = that; <-- THIS CAUSES THE ERROR
    frame[0].contentWindow.Logger = function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    };
});
this.$element.empty();
this.$element.append(frame);
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening as I think that I've enabled CORS support correctly, so any pointers would be appreciated.